# Extract persistent data from blackberry os 5/6/7

Tags: blackberry

I am writing a blackberry application and in the app I store some data using the persistence API. I just wanted to know if there's a way to extract the data (from "outside" the app) to a pc to view/edit? Thanks.

Comment: Please show us some sample code for how you're persisting the data.

Comment: I found this link that does both persisting and synchronization and I'm now going to follow that example. http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Backup-and-restore-small-amounts-of-data-using-SyncItem/ta-p/444763

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `net.rim.device.api.synchronization` API.

Check out the syncdemo in the blackberry code samples for implementation details.